# How to get back two finger scrolling on HP notebook?

Tags: windows-8, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

I am using the HP Pavilion 14-B030TU Notebook with Windows 8. I have had it for 5 days now and the two finger scrolling has been working for the first 4 days. Recently, I had to do a Windows Update as well as update a few apps in the Windows Store. After all these updates the two finger scrolling did no longer work.

I have the two finger scrolling enabled in the Synaptics TouchPad options as shown in this image:

[image: 1]

Next I downloaded [this driver](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) and unzipped and installed the file. I restarted the computer but the two finger scroll still did not work.

How can I get the 2 finger scrolling back onto my HP Notebook?

Comment: If you have a usb mouse, you may try compleatly uninstalling the driver first before re-installing